# Soci: Create Custom class to store results

Tags: c++, soci

I use [Soci](http://soci.sourceforge.net) to make database queries. Now I need to have a custom resultset class that will wrap around soci::rowset. I cannot get it work in the way my code are below simply because copy constructor is private in soci (not supported according to source file). How can I accomplish having wrapper with list of soci::rows (hereby typedef-ed to Row) without complicated code? Any design or direction on how to go about is appreciated

**my header file**

```
typedef soci::row Row; 


class ResultSet
{
public:
    ResultSet();
    ~ResultSet();
    void Copy(soci::rowset<soci::row>& rs);

    Row GetNextRow();
    bool HasRows();

private:
    soci::rowset<soci::row> m_rows;
    soci::rowset_iterator<soci::row> m_iterator;
    bool m_isAccessed;//if first access on row is done
};
```

**source file**

```
ResultSet::ResultSet() {
    m_isAccessed=false;
}

ResultSet::~ResultSet() {

}

Row ResultSet::GetNextRow() {
    if(m_isAccessed) {
        m_iterator++;//increment row
        m_isAccessed=true;
    }
    return *m_iterator;
}

bool ResultSet::HasRows() {
    return m_iterator!=m_rows.end();//it have not reached the end yet;
}

void ResultSet::Copy(soci::rowset<soci::row>& rs) {
    m_rows = rs;
    m_iterator = rs.begin();//put it at row 1
}
```

and here is how I use in ExecuteQuery function of connection. m_session is soci::session

```
void ConnectionMgr::ExecuteQuery(wxString& sql, ResultSet& rs) {
    try { 
        soci::rowset<soci::row> rsInternal = m_session.prepare<<sql.ToStdString();
        rs.Copy(rsInternal); 
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
        m_error = wxString::Format(wxT("SqlQuery close error:%s\n"), e.what());
    }
}
```

example of how I want to use the class later

```
wxString sql = wxT("-- a query\n SHOW DATABASES;"); 
                ResultSet rs;
                m_conn->ExecuteQuery(sql, rs);
                while(rs.HasRows())
                {
                    wxString name = wxString(rs.GetNextRow().get<std::string>(0));
                    //work with name here
                }
```

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what it is that you are trying to do, keeping in mind that rowset's iterator may only be used once.

Comment: I changed Idea as Soci was not the best choice for my project (may be my understanding of it is so limited that I cannot utilize it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOCI have many limitation and undertaking such task seems to be impossible without modifying sources which would mean you have to maintain changes yourself (unless the developers accepts patches which is a probability).

Since I use wxWidgets, I decided to revive databaselayer as [wxDatabase](https://github.com/mtangoo/wxDatabase) and will use that and maintain it